# Ubuntu 12.04 MD5 doesn't match

Tags: 12.04, md5sum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MD5 mismatch on my 12.04 ISO, what is going on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125412/md5-mismatch-on-my-12-04-iso-what-is-going-on)

I downloaded Ubuntu desktop i386 12.04 from http://na.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ubuntu-releases/ and the MD5 does not check. I know there have been some troubles with MD5 just after release, so I was wondering if everything is ok now and I just need to re-download the iso ;)
Thanks a lot ;)