# What are implications of downloading buggy 12.04 iso

Tags: 12.04, iso

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MD5 mismatch on my 12.04 ISO, what is going on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125412/md5-mismatch-on-my-12-04-iso-what-is-going-on)

I see from [question #125412](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125412/md5-mismatch-on-my-12-04-iso-what-is-going-on) that those who downloaded the 12.04 iso image shortly after release may have got an iso with serious bugs, and if they did not check the md5sum then they would not know this.  What are the implications of this?  Will they have problems installing or will the install go ok and after updating the bugs will be fixed automatically?

Answer (score 1):

As someone who downloaded and did a fresh install last night, it's all good.

[image]